# Metal Shader vertex attributes - cannot convert attribute from MTLAttributeFormatUInt to float1

Tags: ios, graphics, metal, metalkit

I have a shader that looks like this:

```
struct VertexIn {
  float a_customIdx [[attribute(0)]];
  ...
};

vertex vec4 vertex_func(VertexIn v_in [[stage_in]], ...) {...}
```

In my buffer I'm actually passing in a `uint32_t` for `a_customIdx`, so in my `MTLVertexAttributeDescriptor` I specify its type to be `MTLAttributeFormatUInt`. When I create the `RenderPipelineState` I get the error:

`cannot convert attribute from MTLAttributeFormatUInt to float1`

I get the same error if I use `MTLAttributeFormatInt`, but can successfully convert a `MTLAttributeFormatUShort`.

Why is this not a valid operation? According to the [documentation for format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlvertexattributedescriptor/1516081-format?language=objc), "Casting any MTLVertexFormat to a float or half is valid".

I know there are multiple ways I can get around this problem, but I'm curious about why this is invalid - perhaps there's something about alignments and byte sizes I'm missing here.